# Process different colum with different pre-processing process

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have the following df

```
         text     count     daytime        label
   I think...        4      morning          pos
You should...        3    afternoon          neg
    Better...        7      evening          neu
```

I tried to only preprocess the `text` column using ColumnTransform by using

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

transformer = ColumnTransformer([
    ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1)), 'text')
], remainder='passthrough')
```

It worked fine. Then I want to apply `count` and `daytime` respectively by using the following code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

transformer = ColumnTransformer([
    ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1)), 'text'),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler(), 'count'),
    ('enc', OneHotEncoder(), 'daytime')
], remainder='passthrough')

X_transformed = transformer.fit_transform(X)
```

It gave me error

```
1D data passed to a transformer that expects 2D data. Try to specify the column selection as a list of one item instead of a scalar.
```

I think the problem is with standardscaler, where it only passes 1D. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate each tuple in the list of tuples with commas. Since `StandardScaler` and `OneHotEncoder` expect 2D inputs, you should, as the error message suggests, pass the column selectors as a list of one item for these transformers:

```py
transformer = ColumnTransformer([
    ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1)), 'text'), 
    ('scaler', StandardScaler(), ['count']),  
    ('enc', OneHotEncoder(), ['daytime'])
], remainder='passthrough')
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed that. But then it throws back an error ```1D data passed to a transformer that expects 2D data. Try to specify the column selection as a list of one item instead of a scalar.``` when I apply that  ```X_trans = transformer.fit_transform(X)```.  I think the error is come from standardsscaler

Comment: @Nankatsu this is because `StandardScaler` and `OneHotEncoder` expect 2D arrays as input. As the error message suggests, you should pass the column selectors as a list of one item. Edited my answer accordingly.